# what is the best way to draw diagram in latex (like family tree)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, diagrams, draw

What is the easiest way to draw a tree like this. I am using pdflatex.

[image]

I tried with this, but it got missed up taken from [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158940/distance-between-tree-levels-in-tikz-edges-and-node-centering/158943), i am having many issues such as the height of the fork is too much (how can i make it dynamic). (2) how can i control the horizontal spacing among children to avoid overlapping as i got down there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]


\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={draw=black,thin, minimum height=1.5em},
    supervisor/.style={%
    align=center,
        edge from parent fork down,
        level distance=0.1cm,
        align=center,},
    area/.style={%
        text centered, text width=3cm,
        level distance=4cm,
        fill=gray!10,draw,
        -latex},
    method/.style={%
   thick,anchor=west, minimum height=2.5em,
        grow=down, xshift=-1.1cm, % Horizontal position of the child node
        text centered, text width=3cm,
        edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.205) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)},draw, -latex},
    level1/.style ={level distance=1.5cm},
    level2/.style ={level distance=3cm},
    level3/.style ={level distance=4.5cm},
    level4/.style ={level distance=6cm},
    level5/.style ={level distance=7.5cm},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
    level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm},
]
%   \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,3);

    % Supervisor
    \node[anchor=south,supervisor,align=center]{Base}
    [edge from parent fork down]

    % Teammate and Subordinates
    child{
        node [area] {Attributable \\ Measurements}  
        [edge from parent fork down]  
             child{ 
             node [area] {Attributable \\ Measurements}
                    }
            child{  
                             node [area] {Attributable \\ Measurements}
                                    }
      }
    %
    child{node [area] {Teammate2\\Position2\\Location2}
        child[method,level1] {node {Subordinate1}}
        child[method,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
        child[method,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
        child[method,level4] {node {Longtext-\\area}}}; 
%\shade[shading=Mandelbrot set] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is an org chart}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? From your picture, it looks like you are on a good path, the `trees` package is a good way to do it. A few pointers: using names `level1` and `level 1` as definitions is confusing at best. Put your style definitions into one logical block; `append` is used inside a scope, where you locally want to add to a prior definition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am facing many issues such as the overlapping. How can i solve this issue (or make children spacing dynamic) and how can i control the height to make it look better. I updates the question. thank you.

Comment: If it is the first time that you create a tree, it might be worthwhile to go through the tutorial in chapter five of the `pgf` manual, http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf   I am by no means an expert in `trees`; the level distance can be manually controlled by changing `level 1/.style={level distance=2.5cm}`, sibling distance by choosing a higher value for the sibling distance in `level 1` again.

Comment: Forest can handle much of the layout automatically, although you may need to help it if it gets too complex. The edges library has a `folder` style which would handle the directory-style part of your tree. There are some examples on the site showing how to handle the switch of direction. Make sure you have version 2 and that you use an example based on the `edges` library.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339891/, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340528/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337867/using-the-package-tikz-to-create-a-diagram/337882#337882. (Sorry, these are my answers because I could find them easily.) These are all basically the structure you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your tree is like a family tree, you may consider to use a family tree drawing package like [genealogytree](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree).

There is no option to switch the growing direction, but all distances are computed automatically. The original picture could be drawn like this:

[image]

The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[templates]{genealogytree}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{genealogypicture}[
  template=signpost,
  level distance=10mm,
  level size=8mm,
  node size=15mm,
  box={colback=white,sharp corners,fontupper=\sffamily},
  mark/.style={box={colback=blue!20}},
  edges={foreground={line width=1pt,red,-LaTeX,},background={line width=2pt,white}}
  ]
child{
  g{root}
  child{ g{l}
    child{ g{lx1}
      child{ g[mark]{lx11}
        c[mark]{lx111} c[mark]{lx112}
      }
      c[mark]{lx12} c[mark]{lx13} c[mark]{lx14}
    }
    child{ g{ll1}
      child{ g{ll11}
        c[mark]{ll111}
      }
      child{ g{ll12}
        c[mark]{ll121} c[mark]{ll122}
      }
    }
  }
  child{ g{r}
    child{ g{r1}
      child{ g{r11}
        c[mark]{r111} c[mark]{r112}
      }
      child{ g{r12}
        c[mark]{r121} c[mark]{r122}
      }
    }
  }
}
\end{genealogypicture}
}
\caption{This is an org chart}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not exactly 'the original picture' but +1 for being able to use the package. (I'm not sure if you wrote it, but either way.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method using an updated and tweaked version of `dir tree switch forking`, which I used in the answer I linked earlier.

A `coordinate`-shaped node is used to adjust for the fact that the switch in both growth direction and style occurs at level 2 for the left branch (or not at all), but at what would otherwise be level 1 for the right branch. The additional node makes it level 2 for both.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{%
  dir tree switch forking/.style args={at #1}{%
    for tree={
      font=\sffamily,
      fit=rectangle,
    },
    where level=#1{
      for tree={
        folder,
        grow'=0,
      },
      delay={
        child anchor=north,
        !u.parent anchor=south,
        edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-\forestoption{fork sep}) -| (.child anchor)}
      },
    }{
      if={>On<{level}{#1}}{
        forked edge,
        parent anchor=children,
        child anchor=parent,
      }{},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        if content={}{
          coordinate,
          no edge,
          before packing={!u.l sep'=0pt},
          before computing xy={s/.option=!u.min x}
        }{
          content/.wrap value={\strut ##1},
        },
      },
      for nodewalk={filter={tree}{>On<{level}{#1}}}{align to centre},
    },
  },
  align to centre/.style={
    if={>Ow+P{n children}{isodd(#1)}}{
      for nodewalk/.process={Ow+nw{!r.n children}{(#1+1)/2}{{fake=r,n=#1}{calign with current edge}}},
    }{
      calign=edge midpoint,
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  area/.style={%
    fill=gray!10,draw,
  },
  method/.style={%
    thick,
    edge+={-Latex},
  },
  dir tree switch forking=at 2,
  for tree={
    draw,
    align=center,
    thin,
    minimum height=1.5em,
  },
  [Base
    [Attributable\\Measurements, for tree=area
      [Attributable\\Measurements
      ]
      [Attributable\\Measurements
      ]
    ]
    [Teammate2\\Position2\\Location2, area, for descendants=method
      [,coordinate
        [Subordinate1]
        [Subordinate2]
        [Third\\Teammate]
        [Longtext-\\area]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forked tree with direction switch at different levels]