# Tree with different branching at each level with tikz and equations in some leaves

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I would like to draw a tree like this :

[image: Tree with different branch types at different levels]

with the first level going horizontal, the second level going vertically and then again stack horizontally on the 3rd and higher levels.
So far I have been trying with this answer : [How to get, both fork down and right in a TikZ tree or diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88500/how-to-get-both-fork-down-and-right-in-a-tikz-tree-or-diagram)

but I did not manage to modify the 3rd level like I want to.

This is the code I have (from [How to get, both fork down and right in a TikZ tree or diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88500/how-to-get-both-fork-down-and-right-in-a-tikz-tree-or-diagram)) :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\forestset{%
  dir tree switch forking/.style args={at #1}{%
    for tree={
      font=\sffamily,
      fit=rectangle,
    },
    where level=#1{
      for tree={
        folder,
        grow'=0,
      },
      delay={
        child anchor=north,
        !u.parent anchor=south,
        edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-\forestoption{fork sep}) -| (.child anchor)}
      },
    }{
      if={level()<(#1)}{
        forked edge,
        parent anchor=children,
        child anchor=parent,
      }{},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        content/.wrap value={\strut ##1},
      },
      if={isodd(n_children("!r"))}{
        for nodewalk/.wrap pgfmath arg={{fake=r,n=##1}{calign with current edge}}{int((n_children("!r")+1)/2)},
      }{},
    },
  },
  node title/.style={
    content={\textbf{#1}},
  },
  node descriptor/.style={content+={\\#1}},
  title splitter/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      split option={content}{:}{node title,node descriptor},
    },
  },
  title split/.style={
    for tree={title splitter},
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  dir tree switch forking=at 1,
  title split,
  where level=0{align=center},
  for tree={draw},
  [Title
    [Level 1
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2
            [Level 3]
            [Level 3]
            [Level 3]
            [Level 3]
        ]
        [Level 2]
    ]
    [Level 1
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2
            [Level 3]
            [Level 3]
            [Level 3]
            [Level 3]
            [Level 3]
            [Level 3]
            [Level 3
                [Level 4]
                [Level 4]
            ]
            ]
        ]
    [Level 1
      [Level 2]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

There is however an issue with this : the PDF fails to compile when I write an equation in one of the slots. Is it possible to write equations in the "forest" branches ?

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Since you’ve already got something partially working, edit your question to show the code you have and people can help with the part you’re having trouble with.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed `{text width=30mm}` out. You can change the content of this argument, but you can't drop the argument because `where level=<number>{<arg>}{<arg>}` has to take that form. There's no general problem with including maths. You can use `math content` as an option for a node (or globally) or you can use `$...$` or `\(...\)`. Display maths would be a different question.

[image: working example with a couple of inline equations]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\forestset{%
  dir tree switch forking/.style args={at #1}{%
    for tree={
      font=\sffamily,
      fit=rectangle,
    },
    where level=#1{
      for tree={
        folder,
        grow'=0,
      },
      delay={
        child anchor=north,
        !u.parent anchor=south,
        edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-\forestoption{fork sep}) -| (.child anchor)}
      },
    }{
      if={level()<(#1)}{
        forked edge,
        parent anchor=children,
        child anchor=parent,
      }{},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        content/.wrap value={\strut ##1},
      },
      if={isodd(n_children("!r"))}{
        for nodewalk/.wrap pgfmath arg={{fake=r,n=##1}{calign with current edge}}{int((n_children("!r")+1)/2)},
      }{},
    },
  },
  node title/.style={
    content={\textbf{#1}},
  },
  node descriptor/.style={content+={\\#1}},
  title splitter/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      split option={content}{:}{node title,node descriptor},
    },
  },
  title split/.style={
    for tree={title splitter},
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  dir tree switch forking=at 1,
  title split,
  where level=0{align=center}{align=left},
  for tree={draw},
  [Title
    [Level 1
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2]
        [Level 2:describe]
        [Level 2
          [{$x^2 + 1 = 0$}]
            [Level 3]
            [Level 3]
            [Level 3]
        ]
        [Level 2]
    ]
    [Level 1
      [Level 2]
      [Level 2
      [{$\Pr (A/B) = \frac{\Pr(B/A)}{\Pr(B)}$} ]
          [Level 3]
          [Level 3]
          [Level 3]
          [Level 3]
          [Level 3]
          [Level 3
              [Level 4]
              [Level 4]
          ]
        ]
    ]
    [Level 1
      [Level 2]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```